# How to configure routes to have default Get and named Get method in WebApiConfig?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to create the following API:

- /api/verifications/1
- /api/verifications/getfoo/1

Controller methods:

```
public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

public string GetFoo(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }
```

WebApiConfig:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithId", "Api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }, new { id = @"\d+" });
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", "Api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

With such config I can access `/api/verifications/getfoo/1` but the `/api/verifications/1` cause an exception: *Multiple actions were found that match the request*.

How can I configure routes to have default Get and named Get method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to specify the `action` for the first route. e.g:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithId", "Api/{controller}/{id}", new { action = "Get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }, new { id = @"\d+" });
```

Comment: Correct, that's the information missing in the URL, so it must be in the mapping ... to distinguish them

Answer (score 0):

Here you're ignoring standard naming convention for action names. Usually `Get` method is bound to request with no parameters to return all available items. As for me, it's better to define different certain name for each action, like `GetOneKindOfThings` and `GetOtherKindOfThings` to make your API more self descriptive.

Anyway you could use the following trick to let framework understand your routes correctly:

```
public string Get(int defaultId)
        {
            return "value";
        }

public string GetFoo(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }
```

---

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithId", "Api/{controller}/{defaultId}", new { defaultId = RouteParameter.Optional }, new { id = @"\d+" });
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", "Api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```